# Postgresql.app user database deleted. How to recreate?

Tags: macos, postgresql, heroku

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails app for use on Heroku and want to use `postgresql.app` locally for the development environment (mostly to play with Rails 4.0's new array attributes.)  I had installed postgresql.app a while ago when playing around with it, then uninstalled and deleted the user database it initially created.  I've now reinstalled the app, but it tries to connect to that database before it'll do anything, including allowing me to do anything with psql at the command line.

If I use psql at the command line, it does this:

> psql: FATAL:  database "bcarr" does not exist

logout

Any suggestions for how to reset the app's settings so it can recreate that initial user db, or how I can recreate that db?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is `bcarr` your username? what happens if you run `psql -d template1` ?

Comment: That worked, and allowed me to create a new database as well as recreate the original bcarr database, thanks!  After your suggestion, I also just figured out I could use createdb at the command line.  Thanks!

Comment: ok, I've elaborated a bit and submitted it as an answer then

Answer (score 2):

Normally on installation `postgres.app` creates a database and a username that matches your OS username (and has db superuser privileges). But in case of a reinstall, it seems that you may end up with that database missing.

However if the username is still there and still superuser, it's still possible to connect with it to `template1` and issue administration commands such as `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE USER`.

The command is simply:
`psql -d template1 -U username`, the `-U username` being optional if it's the same as your OS user.